# Set background color to DotNet.Highcharts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am using DotNet.HighCharts and I would like to make my charts transparent.

I found an example in Javascript and it is possible by setting backgroundColor to null.

Does anyone know if there is a similar option in DotNet.HighCharts?

Comment: Take a look the answer here: http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/discussions/352566

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `backgroundColor` option to `none`:

```
chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            ...
        },
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/quMJc/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

The actual code needed to use this option in DotNet.Highcharts is something like the following:

```
Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
    .InitChart(new Chart 
        { 
            DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Spline,
            BackgroundColor = null
        })
```

Comment: I tried that and it is not working. Vangi posted the actual solution in the codeplex site of the project

Comment: Nice to know in case I need to use it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I bit old but i came across this questions and I have a good answer.

To set transparent in `HighCharts`, this is the proper way. Of course, any color can be chosen from `System.Drawing.Color`

**Create a color object!** and then assign it in `InitChart`

```
var bgColor = new DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers.BackColorOrGradient(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);

DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")            
.InitChart(new Chart { 
                DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Line,
                BackgroundColor = bgColor
            })
```